# Unmet dependencies error in Lubuntu while installing Zoom

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, lubuntu, dependencies, zoom-meeting

I am trying to install the Zoom app in my Lubuntu 18.04 laptop, but I have the issue shown below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxcb-xtest0 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxcb-xtest0 is already the newest version (1.13-1).
libxcb-xtest0 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zoom : Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have already tried to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` as suggested in the error message, but it did not work for me. Same situation as before.

Comment: Have you really tried to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`  ?

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: @N0rbert I tried to run sudo apt --fix-broken install ...But it had not worked for me. same situation like before

Comment: @guiverc so now should I upgrade my lubuntu version? or can I continue using this version? Please give me link of articles about it. it may help me

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxcb-xtest0` to the question by editing it. You are probably have wrong repositories set-up. Running 18.04 LTS is normal as for me, I'm writing this comment from Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I'll refer you to https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-18-04-lts-end-of-life-30-april-2021/2466/4 and https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-18-04-lts-is-nearing-its-eol-end-of-life/2442  where I briefly covered the use of `ubuntu-support-status` to view the status for your installed system and its packages.. ie. you can check your own system and what you use...   I use a i386 system so have no choice of later upgrade on that box (but I don't use it for browsing the web, email or anything external so aren't worried enough to switch to Debian 10/11) but upgraded all *amd64* boxes.